# Protecting Variable From Null Value

Tags: vb.net, null

I have some old code that I'm running through to make sure it's as stable as possible. Once in a blue moon, something breaks and leaves a bunch of garbage data in the database so I'm going through to see where a potential error could occur. I've found a bunch of variable assignments that look something like this:

```
myVariable = dr.Item("myItem") & ""
```

If `dr.Item("myItem")` resolves to Null, would the `& ""` protect `myVariable` from being Null and set it to `""` or would the Null cause me problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're guaranteed to get a string back, whether `dr.Item("myItem")` is a string, `Nothing` or `DBNull.Value`.  As per the [documentation for the `&` Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfx50zyk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> The data type of result is String. **If one or both expressions evaluate to Nothing or have a value of DBNull.Value, they are treated as a string with a value of "".**

Comment: Perfect, thank you for clearing that up. I will have to look elsewhere then for potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `&` operator and extra instance of type `String`, which concatenate operator will create.
Use `.ToString()` method

```
dr.Item("myItem").ToString()
```

`DataRow.Item` property return instance of type `Object`. Then calling `ToString()` method of that instance will return what you expected in your case (Item contain value of type `String`)

If item contains `DbNull` value, then empty string will be returned

[DBNull.ToString Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkbzs85t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Or use extension method `.Field(Of T)`

```
dr.Field(Of String)("myItem")
```

[DataRowExtensions.Field(Of T) Method (DataRow, String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx)

If column doesn't exist then `Column not in the table` Exception will be thrown